# Why BuildContext only avaliable in StatelessWidget.build and what is the good way to use it?

Tags: flutter

I already known that build context can be used in StatefulWidget any where but only in build function when using Stateless Widget. There is so many content in widget need to reference the build context like `Theme`, `showDialog`,`Navigator`,`Provider`...
For Example, I have some code below in StatelessWidget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  ...
  _getFirstWidget();
  ...
}

...
Widget _getFirstWidget(){
  return _getSecondWidget();
}

Widget _getSecondWidget(){
  return _getThirdWidget();
}

Widget _getThirdWidget(){
  // use build context here
}
...
```

If I want to use the build context at the end Widget, I think of 3 ways:

1. Pass the build context layer by layer
2. Convert to StatefulWidget
3. Convert the last widget to a Stateless Widget itself (and use the build context in build)

Why flutter make this restriction in StatelessWidget?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure but I think you want the use the BuildContext from the build method in the function '_getThirdWidget()'. You could just pass it as a parameter like below:

```dart
Widget _getThirdWidget(BuildContext context) {
    // Use the context here
}

// Call the function like this in the parent widget
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _getThirdWidget(context);
}
```

Let me know if this answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think you use the first method I mentioned in my question. I need to pass build context through `_getFirstWidget`, `_getSecondWidget` and finally `_getThirdWidget`. It may not be a clean solution, right?

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. No it is not a clean solution but it may be the only option to achieve what you desire. What is it exactly that you are trying to do?

Comment: I just trying to make sure what is the best solution for these cases because it happen very often. And I want to know that why `context` can be use all over the `state` in `statefulwidget` but not able to use in `statelesswidget`?

Comment: You can use the `BuildContext` all over the `state` in `StatefulWidget` because you are referring to it's state. Since a stateless widget does not have it's own state, the `BuildContext` needs to be accessed from within the build method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the method of adding an argument to use context,
Almost every function needs a context argument
this is stupid behavior
StatelessWidget is inconvenient
I try to use StatelessWidget, but end up using Statefulwidget

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).